# Is it okay using role="main" in a <div> instead of <main>

Tags: html, attributes, roles

If I’d written my HTML structure is not including `<main>,<header> or <footer>` but including "role="" atrribute with `<div>`, it would’ve been wrong or not?

For Instance:

```html
<div role="header"></div>
<div role="main"></div>
<div role="footer"></div>




I've just wondered that this "role" attribute's scope and usage in that way. Is this usage has same effect as using seperate `<main>, <header> or <footer>` tags?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `role=main` on the div which is used to identify the main or primary content of a document. This is syntactically not wrong.

However, semantically it is not suggested, and one should use `<main>` instead of using ARIA.

For more details refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/main_role